# Can I Play Battlefield 4 PC Multiplayer against PS4 players?

Tags: battlefield-4

I have Battlefield 4 installed on a PC. A friend of mine has it on a Playstation 4. We want to play together in multiplayer, is that possible? I read something about cross platform not making this possible.

Answer (score 3):

You read right.  [Cross platform play is not possible for Battlefield 4](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/BF4-Cross-Platform-multiplayer/td-p/1780015).  Generally, cross platform play is not a feature in most games, due to the differences in the games code, controls, etc.